# Windows vista firewall exceptions unchangeable

Tags: windows-vista, windows-firewall, exceptions

I want to allow a program (iTunes) through my windows firewall, so i check it in the program or port list under the exceptions tab (in my windows firewall settings), then i click OK. When i reopen the window the box is unchecked again. Which means i can never get the program through my windows firewall. I think this is a problem due to administrators rights. Because I also can not delete the program from the list. I can however delete other programs from the list.

Anybody have any ideas, tips, remarks?

Comment: are you on a domain? firewall settings could be forced by domain policy

Answer (score 1):

Disable UAC, make changes, re enable UAC

From a run command window type: msconfig

Click on the Tools tab. Scroll down until you find “Disable UAC” .

Click on that line.

MSCONFIG - Disable Account Protection

Press the Launch button.

A CMD window will open. When the command is done, you can close the window.

Close MSCONFIG.

You need to reboot the computer for changes to apply.

You can re-enable UAC by selecting the “Enable UAC” line and then clicking on the Launch button.

http://www.petri.co.il/disable_uac_in_windows_vista.htm